# Xamarin.Forms: Styling is not the same for UWP, WinPhone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Android looks like OK. But UWP looks ugly. Font-size is too big. Controls are too big.

[image]

But UWP app is bad:

[image]

Is it possible to make it a little bit the same. I understand it has different theme. But how I can overide it? Change font-size for whole app?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout OnPlatform - it allows you to specify different values for different platforms. If you create some styles for your controls you can set the font size depending on platform using this trick.

There's an example of using OnPlatform on the Xam developer site, half way down this page:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential_xaml_syntax/